# Deleting the browser's cache of one page, from another

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, caching

I'm working on a project where someone set the browser cache for the homepage to expire after 1 month. I lowered the cache for new people but I'm looking for a way to clear the cache of the homepage for those who already received the 1 month expiration date.

I know it's not possible to do it directly from the homepage because the browser isn't even communicating with the server while it has the page in its cache. What I'm looking for is some kind of JavaScript solution to clear the cache from another page. Meaning, I will link people to another page that'll have special code which will clear the browser's cache of the homepage.

What I know won't work is to redirect the homepage to some cache busting version of the URL (a time stamp in the query string). First, the browser won't even see the redirect, since it's not making a request of the server. Second, I can't redirect the homepage because that'll hurt SEO.

Is there a JavaScript call that I can make to force a browser to clear out the cache of another page on the domain?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not spit out some generic code until you get some client info which tells you what content you want to serve that user? Then you can use any of a number of convenient solutions - cookies/hide/show content to suit user/AJAX calls etc.

Comment: I'm not following what you're suggesting. I'm not having a problem with new visitors, I'm trying to clear the browser cache of people who previously visited the homepage. For example, people who visited http://example.com have a 1 month long ttl for the cache. I'd like to clear that page out from a page like http://example.com/clear-your-cache